# Get value based on column name stored in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables structure:

```
"DocumentSubject"
(
  "Id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "Description" text,
  "List1Left" text,
  "List1Right" text
);

"DocumentRegistryAttributes"
(
  "Id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "DocumentSubjectId" integer,
  "Code" text,
  "WorkDetails" text,
  "Name" text
);
```

In `DocumentSubject` there is column named `List1Left` which contains a name of column from `DocumentRegistryAttributes` table f.e. `Code`.
Can I retrieve value of column `Code` from `DocumentRegistryAttributes` based on string column name stored in `DocumentSubject` table?
I need something like this:

`"DocumentRegistryAttributes"["DocumentSubject"."List1Left"]` <-- first get value of column "List1Left" from table "DocumentSubject", and then retrieve this column value from "DocumentRegistryAttributes" table.

Here is fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6cbc3/1

The real problem is, that I cannot use any static conditions in WHERE clause. Each document in `DocumentRegistryAttributes` table can be assigned to different subject in `DocumentSubject` table, and each subject can have different configuration.

Is it possible?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it

Comment: You are essentially implementing an Entity-Attribute-Value design. Nowadays this would be more flexible (and probably more efficient as well) if you store the `DocumentRegistryAttributes` information in a `JSONB` column in the `DocumentSubject` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_jsonb()` to make a JSON for the row from `"DocumentRegistryAttributes"`, with the column names as keys and then select the text from the JSON where the key is the text in `"DocumentSubject"."List1Left"`.

```
SELECT *,
       to_jsonb(dra)->>ds."List1Left"
       FROM "DocumentSubject" ds
            LEFT JOIN "DocumentRegistryAttributes" dra
                      ON dra."DocumentSubjectId" = ds."Id";
```

Comment: I need to try this approach, but I need to retrieve large amount of columns, and I'm not sure if my query will be faster this way, anyway this is a good solution anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, that's right. I edited the answer. Thanks!